# How to share one instance of api data between all components?

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to call data from database using Api when application start and destroy it after app is closed, i need the same instance of data for each component. 
what should i do?

Comment: on application start, call the API and store the result, which you can then pass within/across the components...

Answer (score 1):

In modern APIs such as KoaJs or ExpressJs there is a context object.
Also you can use a middleware to inject your own data.

In Koa there is a state object embedded into the context for every request. you can set this state using a middleware.

Read more here : https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/api/context.md#ctxstate

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need a service. Create a service that makes that api call and use that service wherever you need the data.

[Here is some guidance from angular.io tour of heroes tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Other methods with examples on this [blog](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)